# Transparent lazy makefile in linux

Tags: linux, makefile, lazy-loading

I'm wondering if it is possible to specify a "*Lazy `Makefile`*" in Linux that would furthermore even be "transparent".

**Scenario**:

The `makefile` specifies how several objects should be build:

```
foo : bar baz
    command baz -o foo < bar
image.jpg :
    wget http://somesite.com/image.jpg
```

Without the files actually being present in the directory, the filesystem "shows" them as if they are "made". Programs can "read" these files and when they do, the mechanism starts building them...

In other words, if one runs

```
display image.jpg
```

The environment first checks if the `image.jpg` already exists, if not it is fetched from the webserver and then represented to the user. The user has the impression the files were already there: they show up in the file system, they have properties, can be fed to a command (with `<`). But they are generated if needed and are always "up-to-date".

Answer (score 3):

You could implement this using FUSE (Filesystem in User Space): http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

The idea is simple enough: a sort of "overlay" filesystem where whenever a file is requested, the build system is asked to build it first.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will give it a try. On the other hand it's weird this is not implemented yet. Looks to me like a very useful feature...

Comment: Most people instead add cases for the commands they need, like your `display`, to their build system explicitly (meaning they'd say `make display` or `scons display image.jpg` or something).

Comment: I agree with John: When you say `display image.jpg`, there is no Makefile involved, so you can't "fix" it via Make. If you want, you can define an alias, or write a wrapper script, or use FUSE.